# Padding left and right don't work on link on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have links on a menu with underlines sliding in out when hovered. I'm trying to add padding left and right to my links on my fixed menu, but for some reason the padding don't show.

Heres an image of what I'm trying to achieve (notice how the active links underline is padded left and right, you can see how the line is covering more than just the text)
[image]

Heres my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsrsrs/ht0n8rt3/)

Ive read here on stack overflow that the problem could be the display, i changed it to inline-block or block and that didn't work.

My HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav_Wrapper_dk">

<nav id="dk_Nav" role="navigation" class="cf">

    <div><a href="#home" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll">Home</a>   </div>
    <div><a href="#about" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll">About us</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link3" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Gallery</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link4" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Find Us</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link5" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Contact</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link6" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Catering</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link7" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Blog</a></div>

</nav>

</div>

<div id="home"></div>

<div id="about"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
#nav_Wrapper_dk {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}


#dk_Nav {
    max-width: 1280px;
    /* width: 742.6167px; */
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2001;
}

    #dk_Nav div {
        margin-top: 11px;   
    }



    #dk_Nav #logo_dk {
        margin-top: 0px;    
    }

    .link_Button {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: .7em;
        color: black;
        line-height: 3.3em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .2em;
        padding-left: 12px;
    }

    /* LEFT TO RIGHT */
    .sliding-u-l-r {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .sliding-u-l-r:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 3px;
        width: 0;
        background: transparent;
        transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
    }

    .sliding-u-l-r:hover:after {
        width: 100%;
        background: black;
    }

    .sliding-u-l-r.active:after {
      width: 100%;
      background: black;
    }


#home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: white;
}
```

My JAVASCRIPT

```
// Scroll Menu
$(function() {


  $("nav  a").click(function() {
    //**Add class active to current clicked menu item  and remove class active from other menu item**//
        $(this).addClass('active').parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
//** Smooth scroll Logic **?
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')     && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Your code needs to be in the question itself, like the editor should have told you when you posted your fiddle link.

Comment: Also note that technically we can't edit code from JSFiddle into your question for you because their copyright license doesn't allow it. (CodePen's does.) You're the only one that technically has permission to add your code. Relevant Meta discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4076315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Easy solution

```
.sliding-u-l-r:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    position: relative;
    left: -6px;
}
```

## Better solution

Apply the underline effect `:after` on the parent of the `a` tag

e.g.

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="#home" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll">Home</a>
</div>
```

---

```
.item:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
}
```

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv0bx99k/5/ (made some changes to make this idea work)

Comment: In IE11 your fiddle has the line sometimes appearing above the navbar item for a moment before appearing below it.

Comment: @freginold Thanks. I have removed the need for `float` in the demo. Should work better now.

Comment: @AmosWong Sure does, runs perfect in IE11.